# Sort array of objects by nested object property

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects like so:

```
[
  {
    "id": "07bf4920-55f4-42b4-9413-a0a9246d3e1f",
    "flatData": {
      "name": "Business Unit Commendations",
      "shortIntro": "Recognition for your valued contributions to your business unit.",
      "slug": "business-unit-commendations",
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "e85fe64e-ac34-45fd-aff1-d192c9a0b6e9",
    "flatData": {
      "name": "Pension Scheme",
      "shortIntro": "Pension scheme for all.",
      "slug": "pension-scheme",
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "1769fb14-5daa-42d3-bdb5-5c7e8462952c",
    "flatData": {
      "name": "On-Site Nursery and Childcare",
      "shortIntro": "Sponsored childcare support schemes available at some MOD sites.",
      "slug": "on-site-nursery-and-childcare",
    }
  }
]
```

I wish to order them alphabetically by the name property in flatData.
A lot of the questions I've found dont have nested objects in them so the answers don't fit.

Expected outcome:

```
[
  {
    "id": "07bf4920-55f4-42b4-9413-a0a9246d3e1f",
    "flatData": {
      "name": "Business Unit Commendations",
      "shortIntro": "Recognition for your valued contributions to your business unit.",
      "slug": "business-unit-commendations",
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "1769fb14-5daa-42d3-bdb5-5c7e8462952c",
    "flatData": {
      "name": "On-Site Nursery and Childcare",
      "shortIntro": "Sponsored childcare support schemes available at some MOD sites.",
      "slug": "on-site-nursery-and-childcare",
    }
  },
   {
    "id": "e85fe64e-ac34-45fd-aff1-d192c9a0b6e9",
    "flatData": {
      "name": "Pension Scheme",
      "shortIntro": "Pension scheme for all.",
      "slug": "pension-scheme",
    }
  },
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using `Array.prototype.sort` function.

Inside `sort` function, compare the values using `String.localeCompare` function.

```js
const array = [
  {
    "id": "07bf4920-55f4-42b4-9413-a0a9246d3e1f",
    "flatData": {
      "name": "Business Unit Commendations",
      "shortIntro": "Recognition for your valued contributions to your business unit.",
      "slug": "business-unit-commendations",
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "e85fe64e-ac34-45fd-aff1-d192c9a0b6e9",
    "flatData": {
      "name": "Pension Scheme",
      "shortIntro": "Pension scheme for all.",
      "slug": "pension-scheme",
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "1769fb14-5daa-42d3-bdb5-5c7e8462952c",
    "flatData": {
      "name": "On-Site Nursery and Childcare",
      "shortIntro": "Sponsored childcare support schemes available at some MOD sites.",
      "slug": "on-site-nursery-and-childcare",
    }
  }
]

const sorted = array.sort((a, b) => a.flatData.name.localeCompare(b.flatData.name));
console.log(sorted);
```